# Which kind of normalization to prefer before PCA (generic solution for any factor analysis)

Tags: pca, normalization

I have financial assets with totally different volatilities, thus I must standardize them before PCA, otherwise, assets with high variance may be considered as principle components, which is wrong.

At the moment I am trying to decide among following methods :

- Calculate all in USD, divide each one by volatility or
  deviation coefficient, substract mean
- Get logarithm on each price, substract mean
- Limit time series by [-1:1]

Image below describes how time series look like after transformation, coefficients at the right is the first eigenvector.

**Question** : as you can see on the image, coefficients for each method are quite different and I would like to get an advice about which standardization method looks more appropriate in this case and does not create biases in calculations?

**Purpose** : I do not need unit form vectors, thus, I calculate PCA based on covariance matrix and want to have vectors that really represent projection of specific asset to selected principal component.

- Large copy of the image - http://snag.gy/iaRRP.jpg
- Resulting projection of assets onto first principal component - http://snag.gy/DftMT.jpg

I think, that if second window shows lowest variance it means that usage of logarithms is the best option, am I right?

[image]

[image]